# How to stop epic launcher starts?

Tags: unreal-engine4

Epic launcher starts everytime i open any unreal engine project, or unrealengine editor itself, how to prevent that? Can't see any option that will keep it calm. Have tired to close it 2 times per any operation with unreal engine editor.

Comment: Jut leave it open in the background? I know it is not perfect, but that is what works for me.

Comment: You are cool man, Great advice ) I was searching for something like that.

Comment: By the way, if someone want to stop that annoying thing. Rename epiclauncher exe file.

Answer (score 1):

Add empty PerforceBuild.txt file to `{EngineDir}\Engine\Build`.

Answer (score 0):

On unreal engine forum guys adviced me to rename epiclauncher exe file. There is no another way for now.